# What is the proper term for this kind of aggregation?

Tags: terminology

I have a bunch of values, which I aggregate as follows:

1. Order them from worst to best (whatever this means). The visual image is that of a horizontal line and the worst item is to the left of the best item.
2. Return the item which has 25% (50%/75%) of the items to its left.

I am sure there is a proper term for this kind of aggregation, I just do not know what it is.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Lower quartile? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile

Comment: If this is it - why not arrange it as an answer, so I could credit you?

Comment: More generally, these are called "percentiles."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to the lower quartile: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile